# Problem using awk

Tags: linux, awk

I have a problem using awk. Print, from every file given as a parameter, the number of line that has the length at least 10. Also, print the content of that line(s), except the fist 10 characters. At the end of the analysis of a file print the name of the file and the number of lines printed.

This is what I've done so far:

```
{
if(length($0)>10)
{
 print "The number of line is:" FNR
 print "The content of the line is:" substr($0,10)
 s=s+1
}
x= wc -l //number of lines of file
if(FNR > x) 
{
 print "This was the analysis of the file:" FILENAME
 print "The number of lines with characters >10 are:" s
}
}
```

This prints the name of the file and the number of lines after every line that has at least 10 characters but I want something like this:

```
print "The number of line is:" 1
print "The content of the line is:" dkhflaksfdas
print "The number of line is:" 3
print "The content of the line is:" asdfdassaf
print "This was the analysis of the file:" awk.txt
print "The number of lines with characters >10 are:" 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f
{
    ## Every time we change file, print the data for
    ## the last file read (ARGV[ARGIND-1])
    if(FNR==1 && ARGIND>1){
        print "This was the analysis of file:" ARGV[ARGIND-1]
        print "The number of lines with >10 characters is:" s,"\n"
        s=0;
    } 
    if(length($0)>10){
        print "The line number is:" FNR
        print "The content of the line is:" substr($0,10)
        s=s+1   
    }
}
## print the data collected on the last file in the list
END{
    print "This was the analysis of file:" ARGV[ARGIND]
    print "The number of lines with >10 characters is:" s,"\n"
}
```

If you run this on the files `a`, `b` and `c`:

```
$ ./foo.awk a b c
The line number is:2
The content of the line is:kldjahlskdjbasd
This was the analysis of the file:a
The number of lines with characters >10 is:1 

The line number is:2
The content of the line is:ldjbfskldfbskldjfbsdf
The line number is:3
The content of the line is:kfjbskldjfbskldjfbsdf
The line number is:4
The content of the line is:ldfbskldfbskldfbskldbfs
The line number is:5
The content of the line is:lsjdbfklsdjbfklsjdbfskljdbf
This was the analysis of the file:b
The number of lines with characters >10 is:4 

The line number is:1
The content of the line is: asdklfhakldhflaksdhfa
This was the analysis of the file:c
The number of lines with characters >10 is:1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can put your end-of-file summary in an `END {...}` block - it will get executed as the script exits.

i.e. get rid of the bogus `x=wc -l` and change the `if (FNR > x) { ... }` to just `END { ... }`

Comment: it's not working If I give 2 files as parameters

Comment: yep, that's because an END block runs at the end of ALL input (or on exit), not at the end of every file.  terdon's answer will work for multiple files.  or you could use a for loop wrapper, or construct a list of filenames (with, e.g., find) and pipe into `xargs -n 1` or any of several other methods of running the awk script once per file.